# Extract first value from array<string> in AWS Glue DynamicFrame

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

My Json structure in S3 is as below. I have successfully crawled it into Data Catalog tables and imported it into a DynamicFrame.

```
{
    "ColumnA": "Value",
    "ColumnB": [
        "Value"
    ],
    "ColumnC": "Value",
    "ColumnD": "Value"
}
```

**Schema of the DynamicFrame**

```
root
|-- columnA: string
|-- columnB: array
|    |-- element: string
|-- columnC: string
|-- columnD: string
```

Although columnB is an array type, there is only 1 value in it. I have no control over the source which generates these JSON files so I have to work with this format.

I need to push this to a Redshift table which has the below schema.

```
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
| ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC|ColumnD|
+--------+-------+-------+-------+
```

While column A/C/D are fairly straightforward, **how do I pull the first value from 'ColumnB' array in the DynamicFrame** to be able to write to the Redshift table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`From Spark-2.4+:`**

Use **`element_at`** function to get first value from array

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([("value",["value"],"value","value")],["ColumnA","ColumnB","ColumnC","ColumnD"])
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- ColumnA: string (nullable = true)
# |-- ColumnB: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
# |-- ColumnC: string (nullable = true)
# |-- ColumnD: string (nullable = true)

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("ColumnB",element_at(col("ColumnB"),1)).show()
#+-------+-------+-------+-------+
#|ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC|ColumnD|
#+-------+-------+-------+-------+
#|  value|  value|  value|  value|
#+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

---

**`For spark < 2.4:`**

```
#Using .getItem(0)

df.withColumn("ColumnB",col("ColumnB").getItem(0)).show()
#+-------+-------+-------+-------+
#|ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC|ColumnD|
#+-------+-------+-------+-------+
#|  value|  value|  value|  value|
#+-------+-------+-------+-------+

#using index
df.withColumn("ColumnB",col("ColumnB")[0]).show()
#+-------+-------+-------+-------+
#|ColumnA|ColumnB|ColumnC|ColumnD|
#+-------+-------+-------+-------+
#|  value|  value|  value|  value|
#+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Thank you! Will this solution work when occasionally, 'ColumnB' is not present in the JSON at all (_the source generating the JSON drops the column B when it is null_) ?

Comment: @AzeemShaikh, You can provide **`structtype`** schema while reading json file then spark will always adds `columnB` column!